# Grouping multiple documents with nested array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having documents that are having this structures

```
x = {
       "scalar": 1,
       "array": [
          {"key": 1, "value": 2},
          {"key": 2, "value": 3},
       ],
       "array2": [
          {"key": 1, "value": 2},
          {"key": 2, "value": 3},
       ],
    }
```

and

```
y = {
    "scalar": 2,
    "array": [
        {"key": 1, "value": 3},
        {"key": 3, "value": 0},
    ],
    "array2": [
        {"key": 1, "value": 3},
        {"key": 3, "value": 0},
    ],
}
```

The end results I'm trying to find is this

```
{
    "scalar": 3, # SUM of scalar
    "array": [
        {"key": 1, "value": 5},  # SUM by key = 1
        {"key": 2, "value": 3},
        {"key": 3, "value": 0},
    ],
    "array2": [
        {"key": 1, "value": 5},  # SUM by key = 1
        {"key": 2, "value": 3},
        {"key": 3, "value": 0},
    ],
}
```

I've tried to use double `$unwind` and then do push by. I'm thinking of using `$reduce` to get the final results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- one way to do it, is by facet, you want 3 groupings and facet can do that , like break into 3 seperate parts, to not mix the unwinds, i think this is the most simple way to do it

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R_3057YKKA4)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "scalar": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "scalar": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "sum": {
              "$sum": "$scalar"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$unset": [
            "_id"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "array": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "array": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": {
            "path": "$array"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$array.key",
            "sum": {
              "$sum": "$array.value"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "key": "$_id",
            "value": "$sum"
          }
        }
      ],
      "array2": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "array2": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": {
            "path": "$array2"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$array2.key",
            "sum": {
              "$sum": "$array2.value"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "key": "$_id",
            "value": "$sum"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "scalar": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$scalar.sum",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Other alternative is to unwind both arrays, but then unwinds and groups will be mixed, making things complicated i think.

Also `$reduce` cant be used for grouping in MongoDB i think, because we can't construct dynamic paths.

If group-reduce and have this data (key=key value=value)

```js
{"1" : 5 , "2" : 3}
```

And we see `{"key" 1, "value" : 5}` how we can check if the above data contains the 1 as key? We cant construct dynamic paths, like `$$this.1` . Only way it to convert it to an array and back to object that will be so slow.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll keep discovering the solution to my actual problem. Your help was very nice :D